# Strategy for using command line args with Unity DI?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using the Unity framework to inject a ConfigurationProvider into some of my classes via the following interface:

```
interface IConfigurationProvider<T>{
    T GetConfiguration();
}
```

then, in my bootstrapper with Unity,

```
container.RegisterType(typeof (IConfigurationProvider<DongleConfiguration>),
                               typeof (DongleConfigurationProvider));
```

This has been a good strategy up until now & has allowed me to define different config providers for various implementations & tests.  Now, I'd like one of the providers to use command line arguments to set up a config object, which requires me to pass along the `args` parameter to the ctor:

```
class ProblematicConfigurationProvider : IConfigurationProvider<ProblematicConfiguration> {
    ...
    public ProblematicConfigurationProvider(string[] args) { ... }
    ...
}
```

I've read that I can use `ParameterOverride` to supply an optional ctor argument as such:

```
var configObj =  container.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider<ProblematicConfiguration>>(new ParameterOverride("args", args));
```

However, I'm using DI "all the way" and relying on the container to resolve dependencies down the line after resolving `RootObject` or whatever my top level class is.  My question is, how can I now use the `configObj` object I've just resolved if it's buried somewhere down deep in my dependency graph?  How can I use a resolved object in another call to `Resolve`?  Would it be through a similar use of `ParameterOverride`?  Is there a way to set up the param override somewhere & have Unity use it without actually instantiating `configObj`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this differently. Add a CommandLineArguments class to your project, which just wraps the command line arguments. As part of your container initialization, register that with the container:

```
container.RegisterInstance(new CommandLineArguments(args));
```

Then your ConfigurationProvider should have a dependency of CommandLineArguments, not string[]. From there, it should just resolve everything naturally "all the way down" without using the parameter overrides.

Since your command line arguments aren't going to change, this makes it a lot simpler in my opinion.

Note: I use the CommandLineArguments type because it's a lot more descriptive of what's going on. You could register the string[] directly into the container, but that would feel a little wierd to me, and possibly inject you command line arguments somewhere you don't expect.

Comment: Feels much better this way.  Thanks!